# Method to remove collection from a linked list

Tags: java, methods, collections, linked-list, hashset

I am trying to make a method to remove every appearance of a collection "L2" values from a linked list "L1". I am wondering how to do it. Currently i am thinking of making a HashSet from values of collection "L2" and removing it, i was just wondering if there was a way of making that method with a time constraint of O(n).

Forgot to mention both Linkedlist L1 and Collection L2 are not sorted. Both are made of integers.

Comment: `linkedList.removeAll(someCollection)` ?

Comment: are your collections sorted?

Comment: From what i gather that would make the algorithm O(n*n)

Comment: The collection and the linked list are both not sorted.

Comment: then the best you could do is O(nlogn) without making a dictionary.

Comment: technically even you use HashSet without good hashing algorithm, it will take more than o(n)

Comment: Would it be possible without using a hashset?

Comment: L2 is a collection of integers.

Comment: If L2 is a collection then you could just use L1.removeAll(L2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `remove` on a linked list for an element is not O(1); it is O(n). So you are right in your assessment that calling `remove` for each element of `L2` will give you an O(mn) running time.

To make the whole removal process O(n + m), you can filter values into a temporary list and then rebuild L1, but you will also need a set for elements of `L2` so that you can perform that filter check in O(1) time.

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> removeAll(LinkedList<Integer> L1, Collection<Integer> L2) {
    LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<>();
    HashSet<Integer> L2Set = new HashSet<>(L2); // O(m)

    // first filter elements into temp
    while (L1.size() > 0) { // n loops
        int v = L1.removeFirst(); // O(1)
        if (!L2Set.contains(v)) { // O(1)
            temp.addLast(v);      // O(1)
        }
    }

    // add filtered values back to L1
    while (temp.size() > 0) {     // About n loops
        L1.addLast(temp.removeFirst()); // O(1)
    }

    return L1;
}
```

Note that we're only using `addLast` and `removeFirst`, which are O(1) operations, giving us a linear running time.

This also preserves the original ordering of the elements in `L1`.

Comment: Yes `remove` on linked list in java is not O(1), the `unlink` is.  The remove still has to search for the node at which it is located in the list and then call `unlink`. I deleted my earlier comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `LinkedList.removeAll` on `L1`, using a `HashSet` for `L2` if it's not already a `HashSet`:

```
L1.removeAll(L2 instanceof HashSet ? L2 : new HashSet<>(L2));
```

At a higher level, this iterates the `L1` list and removes each element in-place if it belongs to the other collection `L2`.

Internally, `LinkedList.removeAll` uses its `Iterator` to traverse its elements and then uses the `contains` method of the other collection to check if the element should be removed. If `contains` returns `true`, it removes the element by means of the `Iterator.remove` method.

Now, using `Iterator.remove` on a `LinkedList` is `O(1)` worst case because the element to remove is the element currently pointed to by the iterator. And using `contains` over a `HashSet` is `O(1)` average, so the whole solution is either `O(n)` if `L2` is already a `HashSet`, or `O(n+m)` if not. (Here `n=L1.size()` and `m=L2.size()`).

Comment: Very cool! I kept `Cmd + clicking` in IntelliJ until I found this implementation in `java.util.AbstractCollection#removeAll`. It does call `it.remove()` which is indeed O(1) in a `LinkedList`.

Comment: I would suggest @slider to edit their accepted answer and reference this as correct answer. Since this one is not returning newly created "LiknedList"